# Recurly subscription non-prorated

Tags: php, recurly

Currently, I have a recurly subscription setup to start every Friday.

I am trying to create a recurly subscription that is NOT pro rated. The customer pays £33 a week for access (they are sent an item in the post), renewed every Friday.

I would like to start the customers subscription immediately, and then renew every Friday. eg

If they sign up on Thursday - they pay £33.... then they pay a further £33 on the Friday, and every Friday thereafter.

I've gone through the recurly docs, and see that all time based subscriptions which start immediately are pro-rated. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would handle this scenario?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few more options:

- Use the starts_at parameter to have the subscription start on the next Friday. The downside of this method is that the subscription will not become active until that date

  - Create the subscription, then use the postpone method to set the next renewal date. There is no proration with this model. I'd prefer this over the free trial, since the trial language is user-facing and a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I can create a subscription with a one off £33 set up fee. Stick it in trial for the remaining days, and start it on the Friday.

Eg... sign up tuesday - charged £33 setup fee. Trial until Friday. Charged £33 subscription fee.

Comment: I commented on this above - but the user experience in this scenario would be pretty confusing. Their first invoice would indicate a trial period with a setup.

Comment: Problem is, using postpone to indicate a pause... having great difficulty in  this paused scenario of working out the pausing. Eg... customer pauses subscription, but still has access util Friday. I need to know the friday when the subscription should have expired... as postpone effectively keep the subcription alive until the next renewal. Proper pausing would be a killer feature - nobody does it.

Comment: Postpone doesn't indicate a pause - it just changes the next renewal date. The subscription remains in the active state. You can use that in combination with the subscription status to get what you want:
- active subscription + postpone  = extends renewal date
- canceled subscription + postpone = keeps the subscription active until the new date, then it terminates

Comment: Yep - all of these are workarounds. It would be amazing if your api delivered a true paused state. At the moment, I'm not storing any data locally - I interact with recurly directly over webhooks and the api to pull down and manipulate data.